# MassTransit Entity Framework Audit Store SentTime Unavailable

Tags: entity-framework, audit, masstransit

I've set up auditing for MassTransit messages using the Entity Framework store and SQL Server. By default, the audit records table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EfCoreAudit](
    [AuditRecordId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MessageId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ConversationId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CorrelationId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [InitiatorId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [RequestId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [SourceAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DestinationAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ResponseAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FaultAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InputAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ContextType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MessageType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Custom] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Headers] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EfCoreAudit] 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuditRecordId] ASC)
)
```

Which does not include a SentTime column. Instead of adding that property to all application message types so it's contained in the Message column data, I am looking for a more generic solution.

One option would be to add that information in the message headers and another to add a KeyValuePair in the MessageAuditMetadata.Custom dictionary. But it seems to me that the SentTime information should be there by default.

Is there any reason why there is not a SentTime column?

I've looked at the MassTransit code and I see that SendContext and PublishContext interfaces do not have that property, while MessageContext (and consequently ConsumeContext) does.

Is there any other alternative to add that information to the audit records that would be more recommended than the ones mentioned above?

Comment: It's been a while since I contributed some code to this feature and I hardly remember the details. I'd say if you need more data there - please open an issue on GitHub and maybe even submit a PR... If I'd be doing it now, I would add more configuration options.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyZimarev